# Node.js’s spawn, exec, options and encoding

Tags: node.js

Node.js’s `child_process.exec` `options` argument has an `encoding` member, while the `options` argument of `child_process.spawn` don’t, according to my API documentation (Node.js up to date docset).

Why this difference?

Note: I'm new to Node.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`spawn()` doesn't have an `encoding` option because it doesn't buffer any data, whereas `exec()` does. You can call `.setEncoding()` on any of the child process's Readable streams (e.g. `stdout` and/or `stderr`) however and those streams will emit strings of that encoding.